# Translate function not working properly in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a statement in which I need to remove the `'\'`. I am using this:

```
translate((myCustFunc:TextWidth(AdditionalInfo4, 35)),'\','')
```

The inner function is executed but the `translate` function is not.

Comment: Why the parentheses around the function call?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with it. When you say something is "not working" you should say what you mean (error message? wrong output?). We need to see input and output, and evidence of what your custom function does.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Just check your inner function what it is returning.